# Select data in steps and ranges

Tags: order-by, range-types

I have the following GPS data. I'm trying to get trips made by the user based on the engine status, and ordered by date where `engine=1` is a engine start and `engine=2` is a engine off event, so every time I find an `engine=2` I know that is the end of a trip. I need to present these trips in a JSON format (I'm doing that with php) but I'm stuck on getting the actual trips individually.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
mysql> select imei, lat, lon, date, engine from dataGps where imei = '864251020174383';

+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------+
| imei            | lat       | lon        | date                | engine |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------+
| 864251020174383 | 12.137000 | -86.254501 | 2016-10-04 14:15:21 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135400 | -86.253342 | 2016-10-04 14:16:24 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.134140 | -86.251671 | 2016-10-04 14:19:12 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.134770 | -86.250549 | 2016-10-04 14:19:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.249687 | 2016-10-04 14:19:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.136580 | -86.248581 | 2016-10-04 14:20:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137000 | -86.247551 | 2016-10-04 14:20:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137160 | -86.246262 | 2016-10-04 14:20:03 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137080 | -86.245621 | 2016-10-04 14:22:33 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.136490 | -86.243942 | 2016-10-04 14:23:28 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135990 | -86.243080 | 2016-10-04 14:43:05 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.241798 | 2016-10-04 14:43:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.240211 | 2016-10-04 14:47:04 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.132720 | -86.237892 | 2016-10-04 14:49:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.133971 | -86.238281 | 2016-10-04 15:11:27 |      2 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.104250 | -86.253792 | 2016-10-11 20:01:36 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.105340 | -86.251129 | 2016-10-11 20:01:45 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.106010 | -86.249069 | 2016-10-11 20:02:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.102820 | -86.245644 | 2016-10-11 20:02:20 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.087050 | -86.231468 | 2016-10-11 20:02:32 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.065980 | -86.212334 | 2016-10-11 20:02:48 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.065560 | -86.208298 | 2016-10-11 20:02:56 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.064720 | -86.205040 | 2016-10-11 20:03:12 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.064050 | -86.202888 | 2016-10-11 20:03:20 |      2 |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Trip 1:

```
| 864251020174383 | 12.137000 | -86.254501 | 2016-10-04 14:15:21 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135400 | -86.253342 | 2016-10-04 14:16:24 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.134140 | -86.251671 | 2016-10-04 14:19:12 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.134770 | -86.250549 | 2016-10-04 14:19:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.249687 | 2016-10-04 14:19:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.136580 | -86.248581 | 2016-10-04 14:20:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137000 | -86.247551 | 2016-10-04 14:20:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137160 | -86.246262 | 2016-10-04 14:20:03 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.137080 | -86.245621 | 2016-10-04 14:22:33 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.136490 | -86.243942 | 2016-10-04 14:23:28 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135990 | -86.243080 | 2016-10-04 14:43:05 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.241798 | 2016-10-04 14:43:57 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.135820 | -86.240211 | 2016-10-04 14:47:04 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.132720 | -86.237892 | 2016-10-04 14:49:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.133971 | -86.238281 | 2016-10-04 15:11:27 |      2 |
```

Trip 2:

```
| 864251020174383 | 12.104250 | -86.253792 | 2016-10-11 20:01:36 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.105340 | -86.251129 | 2016-10-11 20:01:45 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.106010 | -86.249069 | 2016-10-11 20:02:02 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.102820 | -86.245644 | 2016-10-11 20:02:20 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.087050 | -86.231468 | 2016-10-11 20:02:32 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.065980 | -86.212334 | 2016-10-11 20:02:48 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.065560 | -86.208298 | 2016-10-11 20:02:56 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.064720 | -86.205040 | 2016-10-11 20:03:12 |      1 |
| 864251020174383 | 12.064050 | -86.202888 | 2016-10-11 20:03:20 |      2 |
```

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to set a group (trip), and increase it value every time engine = 2

```
select imei, lat, lon, date, engine, 
       if (@last_engine = 2, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) as trip,
       @last_engine := engine
from   (select @grp := 1) x,
       (select imei, lat, lon, date, @last_engine := engine as engine from locs order by date) y
;


| imei            | lat       | lon        | date                | engine | trip|
|-----------------|-----------|------------|---------------------|--------|-----|
| 864251020174383 | 12,137000 | -86,254501 | 04.10.2016 14:15:21 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135400 | -86,253342 | 04.10.2016 14:16:24 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,134140 | -86,251671 | 04.10.2016 14:19:12 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,134770 | -86,250549 | 04.10.2016 14:19:57 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,249687 | 04.10.2016 14:19:57 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,136580 | -86,248581 | 04.10.2016 14:20:02 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137000 | -86,247551 | 04.10.2016 14:20:02 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137160 | -86,246262 | 04.10.2016 14:20:03 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137080 | -86,245621 | 04.10.2016 14:22:33 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,136490 | -86,243942 | 04.10.2016 14:23:28 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135990 | -86,243080 | 04.10.2016 14:43:05 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,241798 | 04.10.2016 14:43:57 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,240211 | 04.10.2016 14:47:04 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,132720 | -86,237892 | 04.10.2016 14:49:02 | 1      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,133971 | -86,238281 | 04.10.2016 15:11:27 | 2      | 1   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,104250 | -86,253792 | 11.10.2016 20:01:36 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,105340 | -86,251129 | 11.10.2016 20:01:45 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,106010 | -86,249069 | 11.10.2016 20:02:02 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,102820 | -86,245644 | 11.10.2016 20:02:20 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,087050 | -86,231468 | 11.10.2016 20:02:32 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,065980 | -86,212334 | 11.10.2016 20:02:48 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,065560 | -86,208298 | 11.10.2016 20:02:56 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,064720 | -86,205040 | 11.10.2016 20:03:12 | 1      | 2   |
| 864251020174383 | 12,064050 | -86,202888 | 11.10.2016 20:03:20 | 2      | 2   |
```

Then select using trip number:

```
select imei, lat, lon, date, engine
from (select imei, lat, lon, date, engine, 
             if (@last_engine = 2, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) as grp,
             @last_engine := engine
      from   (select @grp := 0) x,
             (select imei, lat, lon, date, @last_engine := engine as engine from locs order by date) y) z
where trip = 1
;


| imei            | lat       | lon        | date                | engine |
|-----------------|-----------|------------|---------------------|--------|
| 864251020174383 | 12,137000 | -86,254501 | 04.10.2016 14:15:21 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135400 | -86,253342 | 04.10.2016 14:16:24 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,134140 | -86,251671 | 04.10.2016 14:19:12 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,134770 | -86,250549 | 04.10.2016 14:19:57 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,249687 | 04.10.2016 14:19:57 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,136580 | -86,248581 | 04.10.2016 14:20:02 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137000 | -86,247551 | 04.10.2016 14:20:02 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137160 | -86,246262 | 04.10.2016 14:20:03 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,137080 | -86,245621 | 04.10.2016 14:22:33 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,136490 | -86,243942 | 04.10.2016 14:23:28 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135990 | -86,243080 | 04.10.2016 14:43:05 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,241798 | 04.10.2016 14:43:57 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,135820 | -86,240211 | 04.10.2016 14:47:04 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,132720 | -86,237892 | 04.10.2016 14:49:02 | 1      |
| 864251020174383 | 12,133971 | -86,238281 | 04.10.2016 15:11:27 | 2      |
```

As far I don't really know final JSON format, I've used json_array function.

```
select json_array(imei, lat, lon, date, engine)
from (select imei, lat, lon, date, engine, 
             if (@last_engine = 2, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) as trip,
             @last_engine := engine
      from   (select @grp := 0) x,
             (select imei, lat, lon, date, @last_engine := engine as engine from locs order by date) y) z
where trip = 1
;

| json_array(imei, lat, lon, date, engine)                                    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ["864251020174383", 12.137000, -86.254501, "2016-10-04 14:15:21.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.135400, -86.253342, "2016-10-04 14:16:24.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.134140, -86.251671, "2016-10-04 14:19:12.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.134770, -86.250549, "2016-10-04 14:19:57.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.135820, -86.249687, "2016-10-04 14:19:57.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.136580, -86.248581, "2016-10-04 14:20:02.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.137000, -86.247551, "2016-10-04 14:20:02.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.137160, -86.246262, "2016-10-04 14:20:03.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.137080, -86.245621, "2016-10-04 14:22:33.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.136490, -86.243942, "2016-10-04 14:23:28.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.135990, -86.243080, "2016-10-04 14:43:05.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.135820, -86.241798, "2016-10-04 14:43:57.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.135820, -86.240211, "2016-10-04 14:47:04.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.132720, -86.237892, "2016-10-04 14:49:02.000000", 1] |
| ["864251020174383", 12.133971, -86.238281, "2016-10-04 15:11:27.000000", 2] |
```

Or a json_object function:

```
select json_object('imei',imei,'lat',lat,'lon',lon,'date',date,'engine',engine)
from (select imei, lat, lon, date, engine, 
             if (@last_engine = 2, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) as trip,
             @last_engine := engine
      from   (select @grp := 0) x,
             (select imei, lat, lon, date, @last_engine := engine as engine from locs order by date) y) z
where trip = 1
;


| json_object('imei',imei,'lat',lat,'lon',lon,'date',date,'engine',engine)                                            |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| {"lat": 12.137000, "lon": -86.254501, "date": "2016-10-04 14:15:21.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.135400, "lon": -86.253342, "date": "2016-10-04 14:16:24.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.134140, "lon": -86.251671, "date": "2016-10-04 14:19:12.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.134770, "lon": -86.250549, "date": "2016-10-04 14:19:57.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.135820, "lon": -86.249687, "date": "2016-10-04 14:19:57.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.136580, "lon": -86.248581, "date": "2016-10-04 14:20:02.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.137000, "lon": -86.247551, "date": "2016-10-04 14:20:02.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.137160, "lon": -86.246262, "date": "2016-10-04 14:20:03.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.137080, "lon": -86.245621, "date": "2016-10-04 14:22:33.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.136490, "lon": -86.243942, "date": "2016-10-04 14:23:28.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.135990, "lon": -86.243080, "date": "2016-10-04 14:43:05.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.135820, "lon": -86.241798, "date": "2016-10-04 14:43:57.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.135820, "lon": -86.240211, "date": "2016-10-04 14:47:04.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.132720, "lon": -86.237892, "date": "2016-10-04 14:49:02.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 1} |
| {"lat": 12.133971, "lon": -86.238281, "date": "2016-10-04 15:11:27.000000", "imei": "864251020174383", "engine": 2} |
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/TGLM4008